# How do I override base class methods in Python conditionally on whether they exist?

Tags: python, metaclass

I have a classes `BasicEvidenceTarget` and `SchedulableSoma`.  Sometimes I inherit from `SchedulableSoma, BasicEvidenceTarget`, sometimes I inherit from `SchedulableSoma` alone.  When I inherit from `SchedulableSoma, BasicEvidenceTarget`, I want `SchedulableSoma` to override the method `BasicEvidenceTarget.inject_basic_evidence`.  What's a nice way of doing that?

The override looks like this:

```
class SchedulableSoma(SchedulableCluster, Soma):
    # This is a possible overload of this method in BasicEvidenceTarget.
    def inject_basic_evidence(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().inject_basic_evidence(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ask_for_reschedule()
```

Right now I am unconditionally overriding the base class method, and so if it doesn't exist, there is a bit of method pollution: if the override is called, the call super will fail.  It would be nicer to conditionally generate the override.

I feel like there is a `__prepare_subclass__` magic that might work, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off creating a separate `Both` class for the combo, and overriding the method in that class.  Then either inherit from `Both` or from `SchedulableSoma`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: The problem is that there are three classes like `BasicEvidenceTarget` — each of which has one method that `SchedulableSoma` wants to override.  I don't want to create 8 classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a factory function to generate an appropriate class at the time you define the class that is inheriting it.  This is just a sketch:

```
def makeSubclass(otherclass):
    class MixedClass(otherclass):
        if otherClass == BasicEvidenceTarget:
            def inject_basic_evidence(...):
                # ...
        elif otherClass == WhateverOtherClass:
            def some_other_method(...):
                # ...
```

Then you would do:

```
class SchedulableSoma(makeSubclass(BasicEvidenceTarget)):
    # ...
```

Another possibility is simply to define all the methods in SchedulableSoma, but include checks in them that raise exceptions if the current instance does not inherit from the appropriate class.  Something like:

```
class SchedulableSoma(object):               
    def inject_basic_evidence(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(self, BasicEvidenceTarget):
            raise TypeError("Cannot call inject_basic_evidence unless you inherit from BasicEvidenceTarget")

    def some_other_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(self, SomeOtherClass):
            raise TypeError("Cannot call some_other_method unless you inherit from SomeOtherClass")

    # similar checks for other classes
```

This way the call to `inject_basic_evidence` will fail right away with a more specific error message, rather than failing on the `super` call with a more obscure message about "super object has no attribute" or the like.

Ultimately you might want to think about whether there is a more robust way to structure your class hierarchy.  It is somewhat magical to have classes alter their own behavior depending on whether certain other classes also appear in the inheritance hierarchy, and it may confuse users or lead to unforeseen interactions among the classes down the road.

Comment: Nice solution. But i think your advice to restructure is the best part of the answer. It is hard to know, but this seems like a good case for composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

What you attempting to do is impossible at class definition time without funcy metaclass business. This could be done at instance creation time with the following code:

```
class SchedulableSoma(SchedulableCluster, Soma):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        if hasattr(self,"inject_basic_evidence"):
             def inject_basic_evidence(*args, **kwargs):
                 super().inject_basic_evidence(*args, **kwargs)
                 self.ask_for_reschedule()
             self.inject_basic_evidence = inject_basic_evidence
```

**NOTE: This does not work if a subclass of `SchedulableSoma` overrides `inject_basic_evidence`**

Comment: This solution won't work if a child class also overrides this method, right?

Comment: You are right. No, it won't. Are you actually trying to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I think that this problem could be solved by different inheritence schema. Using your idea:

```
class YourClass(SchedulableSoma, BasicEvidenceTarget):
    def inject_basic_evidence(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(self, BasicEvidenceTarget):
            BasicEvidenceTarget.inject_basic_evidence(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().inject_basic_evidence(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ask_for_reschedule()
```

Or

```
class YourClass(SchedulableSoma, BasicEvidenceTarget):
    if issubclass(YourClass, BasicEvidenceTarget):
        def inject_basic_evidence(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().inject_basic_evidence(*args, **kwargs)
            self.ask_for_reschedule()
```

Comment: But I want the method not to exist at all if it's not an instance of that base class…

Comment: issubclass magic before function definition might do the trick.

Comment: @SzymonZmilczak: You can't do that because `YourClass` doesn't exist yet at the time the class body is being executed.

Comment: For the record, I don't think anyone should downvote new users below zero.  I hope you keep answering and asking questions.  That's how I learned Python.  :)